# Force datetime with hour and minutes to null pandas

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I want to cut the hours / minutes on the following data to keep only the 'YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00'.

Is it a shortest way than this one (I want to get a datetime[ns]) as result and why np.array() force a timezone... ?

```
In[229]: index = pd.date_range('2015-01-01', freq = 'H', periods=10)
In[230]: df = pd.DataFrame(index = range(len(index)), data=index)

In[231]: df
Out[230]: 
                    0
0 2015-01-01 00:00:00
1 2015-01-01 01:00:00
2 2015-01-01 02:00:00
3 2015-01-01 03:00:00
4 2015-01-01 04:00:00
5 2015-01-01 05:00:00
6 2015-01-01 06:00:00
7 2015-01-01 07:00:00
8 2015-01-01 08:00:00
9 2015-01-01 09:00:00

In[236]:np.array(pd.to_datetime(pd.Index(index).date))
Out[236]: 
array(['2015-01-01T01:00:00.000000000+0100',
       '2015-01-01T01:00:00.000000000+0100',
       '2015-01-01T01:00:00.000000000+0100',
       '2015-01-01T01:00:00.000000000+0100',
       '2015-01-01T01:00:00.000000000+0100',
       '2015-01-01T01:00:00.000000000+0100',
       '2015-01-01T01:00:00.000000000+0100',
       '2015-01-01T01:00:00.000000000+0100',
       '2015-01-01T01:00:00.000000000+0100',
       '2015-01-01T01:00:00.000000000+0100'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

Comment: What version numpy and pandas are you using? I get a timezone of `+0000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just access the `.date` attribute:

```
In [88]:
index = pd.date_range('2015-01-01', freq = 'H', periods=10).date
df = pd.DataFrame(index = range(len(index)), data=index)
df

Out[88]:
            0
0  2015-01-01
1  2015-01-01
2  2015-01-01
3  2015-01-01
4  2015-01-01
5  2015-01-01
6  2015-01-01
7  2015-01-01
8  2015-01-01
9  2015-01-01
```

**EDIT**

if the dtype is `datetime64` then again you can change it by accessing the `date` attribute:

```
In [97]:

df[0] = df[0].dt.date
df
Out[97]:
            0
0  2015-01-01
1  2015-01-01
2  2015-01-01
3  2015-01-01
4  2015-01-01
5  2015-01-01
6  2015-01-01
7  2015-01-01
8  2015-01-01
9  2015-01-01
```

Comment: Obviously yes but if you suppose that you have only the df and not the command to create it ;) ?

Comment: If the dtype is already `datetime` then you can just do `dt.date` on the column

Comment: Thank you very much, it's my need :)

Answer (score 1):

If it's already loaded, you can use the `pd.datetools.normalize_date` function, that's its purpose.

```
In [1]:
index = pd.date_range('2015-01-01', freq = 'H', periods=10)
df = pd.DataFrame(index = range(len(index)), data=index, columns=['Date'])
df
Out[1]:
     Date
0   2015-01-01 00:00:00
1   2015-01-01 01:00:00
2   2015-01-01 02:00:00
3   2015-01-01 03:00:00
4   2015-01-01 04:00:00
5   2015-01-01 05:00:00
6   2015-01-01 06:00:00
7   2015-01-01 07:00:00
8   2015-01-01 08:00:00
9   2015-01-01 09:00:00

In [142]:
df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(pd.datetools.normalize_date)
df

Out[142]:
    Date
0   2015-01-01
1   2015-01-01
2   2015-01-01
3   2015-01-01
4   2015-01-01
5   2015-01-01
6   2015-01-01
7   2015-01-01
8   2015-01-01
9   2015-01-01
```

Note that you can also call normalize on your index: `index.normalize()`